# Font suitable for 3D printing

Tags: 3d-models

I am looking for a font, which is connected and has a good line width (so that it can be 3D printed). Something like in the image below:

[image]

Something like in the image above would be great, but I don't know the name. Do you have a suggestion for a font?

Comment: What is wrong with the font you posted? It looks like you already found it!

Comment: I don't know the name of it. The pic came from a web generator

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260057/site-for-typography-question - which suggest that https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ is the correct place to ask.

Comment: For better or worse, there are websites with access to thousands of fonts. It can take a while to filter down to ones you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular font is [Sarina Regular](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Sarina) and is part of the Google Fonts collection. Just Google "connected handwritten fonts" to find more. Kimberly Geswein does a good selection of handwritten fonts. A lot of them are constant width, but most are unconnected.